# Slick слайдер / Движение от края к краю

Tags: jquery, slick.js

возникла такая задачка, имеется слайдер 100% ширины,имеется slick.js,задачка в том, что слайдер изначально показывает 2 слайда с левой стороны экрана, снизу будут соответственно стрелки,нужно чтобы при переключении слайда, он ехал вправо и слайды не пропадали, т.е чтобы доходил от края до края и тд.

Пробовал задать контейнеру со слайдами ширину 50% а у обертки слайдера убрать overflow, результата не дало((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вам надо, чтобы два слайда просто "гуляли" туда-сюда от края до края, то сделать это можно так: добавляете несколько дополнительных слайдов-заглушек, которые не будут видны (visibility: hidden), ставите rtl: true и infinite: false

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: false,
  rtl: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: silver;
}
.slider {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
.slider h3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <h3>1</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если же Вам надо, чтобы после двух видимых слайдов из-за края экрана выезжали ещё несколько, то без дополнительных "костылей" это можно сделать только справа налево: т.е. изначально два слайда будут показываться справа и потянут за собой к левому краю ещё несколько штук

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: false,
  rtl: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: silver;
}
.slider {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
.slider h3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>1</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>2</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>3</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>4</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>5</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, добрый человек

Comment: @Vearo, рад помочь :)